# The AngularJS element appears in a fraction of a second

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am writing the application in AngularJS. After the page is loaded on a fraction of a second, this program code is displayed

```
<div class="col-sm-4" data-ng-repeat="user in users">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="avatar">
                        <img src="" alt=""/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <a data-ng-href="/profile/{{user.username}}"><p class="personName">{{user.username}}</p></a>
                        <p class="profInfo">Something will be here soon
                            <br/>and here</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

One such split per fraction of second appears. Is it possible to set somehow that this `div card` will show up when the data will be loaded?

Comment: Did the solutions below solve your problem or we misunderstood your question? Please mark one as the selected answer.

Answer (score 1):

Generally ng-cloak is added when you want to hide {{ }} while loading the page. As the documentation states you should add the following css to your project:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
      display: none !important;
}
```

Then you can use the ng-cloak as a class or directive, like so:

```
    <div class="ng-cloak"></div>
 Or
    <div ng-cloak></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just add a CSS class "ng-cloak"  to any elements you want to show only after AngularJS is ready.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

You have to add the required CSS to you styles as per the above documents but that's all.